# Tons of space at the bottom of my blog with Firefox and IE

Tags: blogger

My blog address is http://www.raymondhomesteadprimitives.com

At the end of my blog posts, there is a ton of extra space.  This problem started when I upgraded to the new blogger template called "simple".  Google Chrome seems to have no issues yet both Firefox and IE have the problem.  I want to remove both the extreme gap after the footer section of the blog, as well as the gap between my hit counter and my last post.

Thanks for any help.  I have looked at similar questions on this site, but was not able to find how to fix this problem on my site specifically.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the gray space at the bottom, remove the bottom padding from the body tag. The hit counter is separated from the last post by several other elements, and it's enclosed in the footer. Maybe try taking out     `<div class="widget-HTML" id="HTML1"></div>` and placing it further up in the document.